# Bootstrap menu not working in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with a collapsible bootstrap menu. I'm in the process of redesigning the home page of a Wordpress website. So i made a custom header, footer and template file for that. I'm also using bootstrap for the design.

I enqueue the required bootstrap CSS and JS files; everything else seems to be fine but the collapsible bootstrap menu is not working. I think that the bootstrap js is conflicting with the existing JS of the current theme. I also tried loading the script in the custom header also, but that did not do the needful.

What should be my next step?

Here's [a test page](http://test.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/).

Comment: Welcome to SO! In future, please show you code and not the URL.

Answer (score 2):

If you view your console, the browser is returning the error:

> Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery version 1.9.1
>   or higher

This theme is using v1.7.2

Source: http://test.thedigitalmarketingonline.com/wp-content/themes/theme1887/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js?ver=1.7.2

Answer (score 2):

Your theme is using jQuery v1.7.2 it needs to be at least 1.9.1+ for Bootstrap. Check your theme files for where it's adding jQuery into the header (hopefully using wp_enqueue_script()) and comment out that line. Then add this instead:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
```

If you're using the latest WordPress 3.6 or greater then the bundled version will be high enough for Bootstrap.